# Pytest - Access session_scope fixture on class_method

Tags: python, pytest

I´m using celery fixtures to test a couple of tasks on a project and I´d like to know if there´s a way to access a session scope fixture (celery fixtures are session scoped by default) reference inside a class method:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixture('celery_worker')
class TasksTest(TestCase):

    def test_my_task_a(self):
        tas_info = my_task_a.delay()
        assert celery_worker.something # access the celery_worker reference raises an error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [`pytest` docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/unittest.html):

> Note:
>
> `unittest.TestCase` methods cannot directly receive fixture arguments as implementing that is likely to inflict on the ability to run general unittest.TestCase test suites.
>
> The above `usefixtures` and `autouse` examples should help to mix in pytest fixtures into unittest suites.
>
> You can also gradually move away from subclassing from `unittest.TestCase` to *plain asserts* and then start to benefit from the full pytest feature set step by step.

So, following this advice, you could define a "pass-through" autouse fixture on class level which accepts other fixtures as arguments and stores the references to anything you should require inside a single test:

```
class TasksTest(TestCase):

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def my_celery_passthrough(self, celery_worker, celery_session_worker):
        self.worker = celery_worker
        self.session_worker = celery_session_worker

    def test_spam(self):
        assert 'macbookpro2017' in self.worker.hostname
        assert 'macbookpro2017' in self.session_worker.hostname
```

However, let me repeat the last part of the above quote:

> You can also gradually move away from subclassing from `unittest.TestCase` to *plain asserts* and then start to benefit from the full pytest feature set step by step.

Since you are already using `pytest` features that `unittest` won't understand anymore - why sticking to test classes? Just write new tests as functions from the start, this way you don't have to introduce any workarounds. As for the old class based tests, you can leave them as is for now and rewrite them later, when/if you have to modify them.