# Use Session Scoped Fixture as Variable

Tags: python, scope, pycharm, pytest, fixtures

I am writing tests in pytest and am using fixtures as variables.

Originally, this is how the fixtures looked:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def user(request):
    u = "Matt"
    request.cls.u = u
    return u
```

And then, there was another fixture to delete the user from the database once I finished with it.
In the tests, I used both fixtures like so `@pytest.mark.usefixtures("user", "teardown fixture")`

 The teardown fixture was `class scoped`, until I decided to change it to `session scoped`, since I want to delete the user only after running all the tests.
The problem was that suddenly the teardown fixture couldn't access user, since user is `class scoped`.

I changed the user to session scoped, however, I am not sure how to access, or export it now.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def user(request):
    u = "Matt"
    # request.cls.user = u -> WHAT GOES HERE INSTEAD OF THIS?
    return u
```

User is no longer recognized in the test functions. 
 The test is located inside of a class. The current function is something like this:

```
Class TestUser(OtherClassWhichInheritsFromBaseCase):
 def test_user1(self, user1):
        self.open("www.google.com")
        print(user1)
```

When I try to run the code in pycharm I get the following error:

```
def _callTestMethod(self, method):
>       method()
E       TypeError: TestUser.test_user1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user1'
```

Any advice?

Comment: You can use yield fixtures for your scenario instead of using two different fixtures for setup and teardown

Comment: True, but that still leave me unsure how I access the variable returned from the fixture...

Comment: Not sure if this deserves its own question, actually. Thank you @larsks for helping me figure out what was wrong. This questions helped me understand what was really wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48871972/pytest-access-session-scope-fixture-on-class-method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're approaching this from the wrong direction. If you need to clean up a fixture, you don't write a second fixture; you write your fixture [as a context manager](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#teardown-cleanup-aka-fixture-finalization).

For example, you might write:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def user():
    u = User(name="Matt")
    yield u
    # cleanup goes here
```

And in your test code:

```
def test_something(user):
  assert user.name == "Matt"
```

---

Here's a complete example. We start with this dummy `user.py`, which simply creates files to demonstrate which methods were called:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class User:
    name: str

    def commit(self):
        open("commit_was_called", "w")

    def delete(self):
        open("delete_was_called", "w")
```

Then here's our test:

```
import pytest

import user


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def a_user():
    u = user.User(name="testuser")
    u.commit()
    yield u
    u.delete()


class TestUserStuff:
    def test_user(self, a_user):
        assert a_user.name == "testuser"
```

We run it like this:

```
$ pytest
=============================================================================================== test session starts ===============================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.1, pytest-6.2.4, py-1.11.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /home/lars/tmp/python
plugins: testinfra-6.5.0
collected 1 item

test_user.py .                                                                                                                                                                                              [100%]

================================================================================================ 1 passed in 0.00s ================================================================================================
```

After which we can confirm that both the `commit` and `delete` methods were called:

```
$ ls
commit_was_called
delete_was_called
test_user.py
user.py
```

Comment: Great idea! How would then I refer to u in my test functions, if say, I need to access u's name? (The link doesn't have the session scope)

Comment: You reference a fixture by including it as an argument to a test function.

Comment: It's not working for me... I keep on getting a message `TypeError: Tests.test_something() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'`. Not sure if it changes anything but it's inside a class - I'll update the question to reflect that

Comment: Without seeing your actual code it's hard to tell what's going on. I've updated the answer with a complete, runnable example that hopefully demonstrates things in more detail.

Comment: Would it be expected to work the same if test_user and a_user were in two different classes which were located in two different files?

Comment: I only get the error when the method that wants to use the session scoped fixture is inside a class. Otherwise it works fine. Your example is without a class surrounding them.

Comment: I've updated the example so that the test is wrapped in a class. Still runs without error.

Comment: I managed to run your example with a class totally fine. However, when I tried to inherit from BaseCase (using from seleniumbase import BaseCase), the same error as before appeared. Do you have any idea if inheritance could be a problem with session scoped fixtures?

Comment: At this point, you probably want to open a new question that includes sufficient code in the question to reproduce the problem you're asking about. Without a reproducer there is too much guesswork trying to figure out what your environment looks like.